# Максимально корректная валидация форм в Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Подскажите наиболее правильную последовательность валидации форм в Codeigniter, скажем так - "Железную" на проверку полей форм: `textarea, input, checkbox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А чем описанная [**здесь**](http://codeigniter.su/libraries/form_validation.html) некорректна?

Вроде все написано на русском, и предельно все просто.

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос в последовательности обработки полей, например: `trim|require`.